# Spring MVC Controller called Twice

Tags: spring-mvc

On each request to the URL the mapped controller called twice. I have seen few solutions over the net that says "Remove empty source to href and Images" and "Setting load on start up is Zero in web.xml" but both the solutions did n't work out for me. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question gives no real space for an answer. Provide more information. Which mapping and which requests does the browser?

Comment: for example: http://localhost/xyz/ed-123, when I hit the URL from browser the relevant controller of spring been called twice.

Comment: You did check that the browser send the request only once over the wire? How did you learn that the controller was run twice? Could you do such a request and post the two stack traces entering the controller (in debug mode).

Comment: Browser sent the request only once and I identified this issue by debugging.

Comment: you need to provide your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been called twice due to the below CSS line

```
background: url(../images/header_arrow.png) left bottom no-repeat;
```